# How do I add SQL data to a visio Grid?

Tags: sql-server, visio

I'm using Visio to show about 7 different tables of data. Each table is 8rows x 5cols. The data is all available in a SQL Server.

So whilst I can access the SQL data, and it appears in my "External Data" task pane, I cannot find a way to display it in a "Grid" shape. (Or any other shape for that matter).

Is this actually possible, or am I chasing rainbows?

Comment: I don't know anything about the Grid specifically, but have you worked through [this tutorial](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-data-connection-wizard-to-import-data-into-visio-65295a62-8da3-49bc-8dd8-1f77d0a05127)?

Comment: Yep, and I've got all my data now showing nicely i the task pane. So how do I make that data appear on the page, as a grid? (or a table?)

Comment: What do you meas as 'Grid shape'? You can link one row from 'External data' pane with Shape Data of some shape...

Comment: Lets say my data consists of five rows. I want to show 5 rows of data in my grid.

Comment: **IMHO** MS Visio cant do it "out-of-box", you must write owm VBA-macro or script in another language.

Comment: The same thought had occured to me :/  ... Thanks for sharing